# how to combine jquery code into a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a jquery script into a javascript function and then call that function when `#sortby` is added to the url. Is this possible?

**the jQuery**

```
$("#myselect option[value='availability']").attr("selected","selected");
```

**the Javascript**

```
function sortBy(){
    performanceQuery(perfpage);
    tourQuery(tourpage);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The jquery code is also javascript code.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. jQuery is valid javascript, so there is not issue whatsoever in mixing the two. Also, presumably, "when #sortby is added to link" -> you mean that someone clicks on a link with that achor tag? This is a simple click event. I would suggest to check http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works as this is basic jQuery stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    if (document.location.hash == '#sortby') sortBy();
});

function sortBy(){
    $("#myselect option[value='availability']").prop("selected", true);
    performanceQuery(perfpage);
    tourQuery(tourpage);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is just a Javascipt library that provides some new functions (yes, this `$` is just a funky name of a variable containing function). You can use it wherever you want.